# Is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

I have closed this question [Usamos verbo ou substantivo: "carreteiros em viajem" ou "carreteiros em viagem"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/viajem-ou-viagem) as duplicate of that [Viagem ou viajem?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/981/viagem-ou-viajem).

Although the questions are slightly different the answer can be the same for both questions.
If they can post exactly the same answer it's a very good indication that the questions are duplicate. The @Math answer can be a very good answer to duplicate question. 
So @Math just need to say yes is "carreteiros em viagem" if he answer the duplicate.

If I have a doubt: *"Carreteiros em viajem" ou "Carreteiros em viagem"?* I want to know the difference between *viagem* and *viajem*. Am I right?

What do you think about that?

Comment: The question is open now.

Comment: Only now have I come to this page and read its content. I must say that when I first read the putative duplicate question, I found it strange that someone who can write Portuguese relatively well shouldn't know that "viagem" in "em viagem" is a noun and took it as a joke, not a serious question.  I now realize that the OP is probably a non-native speaker and it must be a real doubt.  For this reason, I've changed my mind and now I'm for reopening, but it has already been reopened anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I filed the petition to reopen the question, so I reckon I should try and present a more compelling defence of it.

In the alleged duplicate the OP thinks the correct phrase is **Carreteiros em + verb**, which he knows is spelled with a **j**. Someone has told him elsewhere (see his first comment to his own question) he is wrong (he is), and he came to us to ask for our view. So this is a **grammar** question, whether **noun + em + verb** is a grammatical construction. The allegedly original question is about spelling and does not address this issue. Now I’ll try and back up each individual point.

The OP knows the conjugations of the verb **viajar** are spelled with a **j**. He writes (first line, third paragraph): “a regra onde diz que é para usar com a letra **J** quando é verbo.” So this is what the allegedly original question clarifies, but the OP knows this already.

The OP thinks **em + verb** is grammatical. He writes (third paragraph):

> “[E]u tenho um sujeito na terceira pessoa do plural ( carreteiros ) fazendo uma ação **viajar** o **em viajem**.

and, even more explicitly, in the following statement, where he thinks **guerra** is a verb:

> "Soldados **em guerra**" onde o **em** esta ligando um verbo **guerrear**

In his comment to [my answer to his qestion](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/viajem-ou-viagem/1046#1046)  he acknowledges that then, after reading my answer and a few comments to his own question and my own answer, he understood that *guerra* is not a verb (he says “realmente não da p/ conjugar ‘eu guerra, ele guerra’”). And from this he understood that **carreteiros em** must be followed by a noun and not a verb.

So I think this makes clear that his doubt was about grammar not spelling. The answers to the other question do no address his doubt, nor is there any reason why they should. Math *might* have included the example **carreteiros em viagem** in his answer. But, first, why should he? Among all the thousands of examples one can build with the noun *viagem*? Second, *even if* he did include this example, it would still not explain to the OP’s satisfaction why you should have **em + noun viagem** rather than **em + verb viajem**. It would only reiterate what someone else had already told him, that the correct form was **carreteiros em viagem** (see his comment to his own question). But he did not understand why that was the case. So he would need to ask a new question. That’s what he’s done.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Lets see what the community thinks about it and I reopen the question if the community doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. The question is confusingly worded and has exactly the same title as the other one. This definitely does not help. Maybe we should edit the title. For instance: "Carretereiros em viagem" (substantivo) ou "Carreteiros em viajem" (verbo)?

Comment: *"Carretereiros em viagem" ou "Carreteiros em viajem" ?*

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu pensei em pôr os parenteses com (substantivo) e (verbo) só para se perceber logo que é uma questão de gramática, mas a tua sugestão é mais elegante. Agora o Math esteve a editar a pergunta, e duas das alterações dele não correspondem ao meu entendimento do original. Devia ser possível nos comentários chamar a atenção dos editores, para podermos discutir estas coisas com ele, mas não é. Havendo divergências no entendimento, o melhor é repôr o original, não?

Comment: Falamos aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado pela dica. Nunca lá tinha estado, mas fui lá, e a conversa com o Math foi muito produtiva. Chegámos facilmente a acordo sobre tudo. Umas coisas sobre as quais estamos de acordo ainda não foram implementadas. Nomeadamente o novo título, para dar oportunidade a mais pessoal de se pronunciar. Se lá puderes ir dar um olhadela, para ver se arrumamos de vez a pergunta.

Comment: Only now have I come to this page and read its content. I must say that when I first read the putative duplicate question, I found it strange that someone who can write Portuguese relatively well shouldn't know that "viagem" in "em viagem" is a noun and took it as a joke, not a serious question.  I now realize that the OP is probably a non-native speaker and it must be a real doubt.  For this reason, I've changed my mind and now I'm for reopening, but it has already been reopened anyway.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion they are not duplicates.

- In the "original" question, it seems to me that the author is asking whether the substantive is "viagem" or "viajem";
- In the "duplicated" question, the author is asking whether the work used in "carreteiros em viajem" is a substantive (viagem) or a verb (viajem); the author even points to a similar example with "soldados em guerra".

Jacinto seems to have the [same opinion](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/viajem-ou-viagem#comment2689_1045):

> @Centaurus O perguntador sabe que a flexão do verbo viajar viajem se escreve com j, e, imagino, que o substantivo viagem, com g, que é o que é tratado na outra pergunta. A sua dúvida, por muito curioso que possa parecer, é se a expressão correta é carreteiros em viagem (com em + substantivo) ou carreteiros em viajem (em + verbo). Portanto é uma questão diferente, mais de gramática do que ortografia. A outra questão é exclusivamente ortográfica.

Comment: ANeves *qual é a diferença entre "viajem" e "viagem"?* is like *"Carreteiros em viajem" ou "Carreteiros em viagem" ?*. We have same problem and one different way to ask. The @Math response can be used to answer the "duplicate" question, right?

Comment: If I have a doubt *"Carreteiros em viajem" ou "Carreteiros em viagem" ?* I want to know the difference between *viagem* and *viajem*. Am I right?

Comment: @JorgeB. No, you could want to know whether _carreteiros em_ takes a verb or a noun after _em_.

Comment: @Earthliŋ If you know the difference between bot you can answer that. No?

Comment: I know the questions are a little bit different but they want the same answer. The difference between *viagem* and *viajem*.

Comment: @JorgeB. I understand, but disagree; one asker wants to know the difference between the two words, while the other knows the difference but wants to know which of them he should use in that case.

Comment: Sou nativo na língua portuguesa ( brasileira ) minha dúvida não era a respeito da ortografia como na pergunta marcada como duplicada, e sim no uso na frase em questão que seria como o Jacinto explicou a forma gramatical em questão

Comment: Only now have I come to this page and read its content. I must say that when I first read the putative duplicate question, I found it strange that someone who can write Portuguese relatively well shouldn't know that "viagem" in "em viagem" is a noun and took it as a joke, not a serious question.  I now realize that the OP is probably a non-native speaker and it must be a real doubt.  For this reason, I've changed my mind and now I'm for reopening, but it has already been reopened anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Jacinto explain it well in the comments: the second question asks whether *carreteiros em* should go with a verb (*viajem*) or with a noun (*viagem*).

The first question has been altered several times, but in its current form it asks about the difference between *viagem* and *viajem*.

I think that Jacinto's answer on the second question gives an answer to the first question, so if anything we should close the first question as a duplicate of the second.

Comment: If the first question as a duplicate of the second, then second as a duplicate of first too.

Comment: I don't think the answers of the first question answer the second question... Since nobody has mentioned it, here's [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) from the Meta FAQ.

Comment: @Earthling thaks for the meta post. I'll try to understand your reason.

Comment: Only now have I come to this page and read its content. I must say that when I first read the putative duplicate question, I found it strange that someone who can write Portuguese relatively well shouldn't know that "viagem" in "em viagem" is a noun and took it as a joke, not a serious question.  I now realize that the OP is probably a non-native speaker and it must be a real doubt.  For this reason, I've changed my mind and now I'm for reopening, but it has already been reopened anyway.